# Deploy multiple Java apps on a server

Tags: java, hosting, telegram

I have recently started playing around with Telegram bots. I found a host (digitalocean) that gives me a linux server that is enough for my needs. The tutorial that I read said that I need to run my jar files using through using the screen command.

However, as my app runs, I cannot do anything else on that screen. I can't start another app on it, either. So here comes the question - how can I host 2 java apps on one server?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This isn't a programming question - read the manual for the screen command. Create a second screen - it's ctrl-A <something> (look it up in the manual) and run your second JVM there, or run both your apps on one JVM.

Comment: they have documentation on this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-byobu-for-terminal-management-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
 nohup java -jar yourapp.jar &